# Odoo testing failed to initialize database

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I was testing Odoo modules, using coverage command, I get the Failed to initialize database error, I think the error is in this line:

`expr="//field[@name='unit_amount']"`, but i don't know how to solve it.

```xml
    <record id="hr_timesheet_sheet_form_inherited_working_type" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hr.timesheet.sheet.form.inherited.working_type</field>
        <field name="model">hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_timesheet_sheet.hr_timesheet_sheet_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='unit_amount']" position="before">
                <field name="task_id" domain="[('project_id','=',project_id)]" attrs="{'required':True}"/>
                <field name="working_type_id"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which are the steps to reproduce the error?

Comment: What is working_type_id? What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Your `xpath` is wrong. The field you are using is in timesheet line and not in the timesheet.

Use following xpath:

```xml
<xpath expr="//field[@name='timesheet_ids']/tree/field[@name='unit_amount']" position="before"></xpath>
```